# EntityFramework one to many relationship repeated insert problem

Tags: database, entity-framework, ef-code-first, code-first, relational

```
enter code here

[Table("Articles")]
public class Article : IEntity
{
    [Required, StringLength(60)]
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    [Required, StringLength(2500)]
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public int LinkCount { get; set; }
    public virtual User Owner { get; set; }
    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
    public virtual Html_Content_Result HtmlPage { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Liked> Likes { get; set; }       
}

    [Table("Users")]
public class User : IEntity
{
    [StringLength(25)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [StringLength(25)]
    public string Lastname { get; set; }
    [StringLength(25), Required]
    public string Username { get; set; }
    [StringLength(100), Required]
    public string Password { get; set; }
    [StringLength(70), Required]
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public Guid ActivateGuid { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Article> Articles { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
    public virtual List<UsersRole> UsersRoles { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Liked> Likes { get; set; }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hX1j1.png)

I have two entity named User and named Article.
I created my db with entityframework codefirst.
There is  one to many relation between this two table.
Problem is when i insert operation to article table i add to the model  user entity from session and inserted repeated entery on my user table beacuse i already inserted my user before.

What should i do for solution?

Comment: Please add your insert code that produces duplicates.

Comment: Of course, I added it below.

Comment: 1) please add it to question 2) please add code that works with entity framework

Answer (score 0):

```
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    [ValidateInput(false)]
    public ActionResult Index(Article model)
    {
        BusinessLayerResult<Article> res = new BusinessLayerResult<Article>();
        res.Result = model;
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            model.HtmlPage.Id = res.Result.Id;
            model.Owner = Session["user"] as User;
            _articleService.Add(res);

        }
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   public int Add(TEntity entity)
    {
        if (entity is IEntity)
        {
            IEntity myEntity = entity as IEntity;
            DateTime dateTime = DateTime.Now;
            myEntity.CreatedOn = dateTime;
            myEntity.ModifiedOn = dateTime;
            myEntity.ModifiedUsername = identity.Id.ToString();
        }
        using (TContext context = new TContext())
        {
            context.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
            var addedEntity = context.Entry(entity);
            addedEntity.State = EntityState.Added;
            return context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are creating new context which does not track your existing user (`model.Owner`). It seems that you have implemented generic repository and I'm not sure how to handle this issue in this case, but in general you will need to add you user to tracked entities either with `context.Attach` or `context.Entry`. Also you can try changing your code to:

```
    using (TContext context = new TContext())
    {
        context.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
        context.Attach(entity)
        return context.SaveChanges();
    }
```